# How to pass same variable value to another in same stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me out I need to pass `@VARY` value to `EXEC FFF @VARY`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XYX_Read
   @VARY int
AS
   SELECT * FROM GGG WHERE VARY=@VARY
GO

EXEC FFF @VARY
GO
```

Comment: next time use more detail as to what the actual problem is and you'll avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that re-passing a variable into another stored proc will fail sometime. You are better off declaring another variable and use that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_ReadData
@VARY int  
AS  

declare @vary2 int
set @vary2 = @VARY

SELECT * FROM GGG WHERE VARY=@vary2

exec sprocname @vary2
```

Comment: Using that I cant't run the procedure, Just getting the column name in the result set instread of command successfully

Comment: I've never discovered any issues using the same variable twice... could you add an example where this would cause an issue?

Comment: @Irvin Dua. I don't understand your problem. Explain more (and put in question).

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson. Not any variable, just re-passing a parameter to another proc. I just remember having an problem getting it to work consistantly - weird errors or maybe I misremember... :P

Comment: @BoojiBoy - I think that you are confusing "parameter sniffing" with passing a variable to another sp, wich shouldn't be a problem at all

Comment: @Lamak that could've been the issue I had, I've never heard of parameter sniffing (Thanks!) I just remember that it didn't work till I created a local variable to pass to the sproc inside my sproc.

Answer (score 0):

You have here two calls to sql server, so - Pass the value of @Vary twice - for each call to sql server.

And actually - it is not **the same stored procedure**